# Angular: Mapping HTTP response with new http client

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a generic API service in my app that makes requests like this to the backend:

```
post<T>(url: string, jsonObject: object): Observable<T> {

    return this.http.post<T>(url, JSON.stringify(jsonObject));

}
```

I use that method like this from my components and try to cast the response as a specific model:

```
this.apiService.post<SomeSpecificModel>('some/path/here', this.usernameForm.value)
                                        .subscribe(
                                            res => {
                                                console.warn(res);
                                            },
                                            () => {
                                                console.warn("error");
                                            }
                                        );
```

My problem is that the API returns content like this:

```
{
    code: some-string,
    type: some-number,
    data: []
}
```

And the `data` property is where the entity is that I want to cast with my model in Angular.

I would still like to have access to both `code` and `data` properties in my component, but I am not sure how to accomplish that.

Can I make a base model that mimics the response from the API and has a generic array property? Something like this:

```
export class BaseModel<T> {
    code: string;
    type: number;
    data: Array<T>;
}
```

And then cast like this?

```
this.apiService.post<BaseModel<SomeSpecificModel>>(...
```

I tried that and I don't get any build errors, but the properties on `SomeSpecificModel` is not mapped.

Comment: Can you show what your object looks like when doing this? e.g. when logging to the console

Comment: Are you sure your data is an array when coming from the server?

Comment: let me know it you need more help

Comment: Define both `BaseModel` and `SomeSpecificModel` as interfaces and let me know if it makes a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something lke this.

Your service code

```
  public fetchData<T>(resourcePath: string):Observable<ResourceData<T>> {
    return this.http.get<ResourceData<T>>(resourcePath);
  }
```

Your component code

```
this.yourService.fetchData<DropDownDataItem>('/your/path/')
      .map((response) => {
        return {
          count: response.count,
          items: response.data
        };
      });
```

Inteface

```
export interface DropDownDataItem {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface ResourceData<T> {
  data: T[];
  limit?: number;
  offset?: number;
  count: number;
}
```

Hope this helps